# Detect if radio button is checked in webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am trying to validate if radio button is checked. I have below html code snippet for radio button .

```
<span class="jquery-hp-radio jquery-hp-radio-checked" style="-moz-user-select: none;">
<span class="mark">
<img src="http://someurl/images/empty.gif">
</span>
</span>
```

Tried with below code -

```
if(driver.findElement(By.className("mark")).isSelected()){
          System.out.println("True");
      }else
      {
          System.out.println("False");
      }     
  }
```

It gives output as False - even though radio button is selected by default.

Comment: isSelected() will only work for a concrete checkbox element such as <input type="checkbox"/>.

Comment: are you using correct locator for the radio button on which you are performing the check? I can see 2 class names.....

Comment: I used xpath instead of className to avoid the conflict but it did not make any difference.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @ Rameshwar

Your solution worked

I was able to detect if radio button is checked OR unchecked `"jquery-hp-radio jquery-hp-radio-checked"` by

```
if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='mark']/..")).getAttribute("class").contains("checked")){
          System.out.println("True");
      }else
      {
          System.out.println("False");
      }   
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that your radio button's `class` is `jquery-hp-radio jquery-hp-radio-checked` when it is checked.

So you do the following to check if the button is checked or not

```
if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='mark']/..")).getAttribute("class").contains("checked")){
          System.out.println("True");
      }else
      {
          System.out.println("False");
      }   
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If radio button is selected by default in the application then use get attribute().

e.g.

```
if (driver.findelement(By.xpath ()).getattribute("componentid").endwith("true")){
system.out.println("selected")
}else{
system.out.println("not selected")
}
```